# How to have an array in a parameter file?

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, yaml, symfony-2.1

I'm using Symfony2.1 and I need to save an array in a config/parameter file because I would modify the content of this array often (probably once every 6 months) (it contains email addresses).

I know that I can save a string in parameters.yml for example using :

in app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters
    address: 'example@domain.com'
```

and retrieving this parameter using $this->container->getParameter('address') in a controller, but I have many recipients and I would like to have something like :

```
    parameters
        address: array('example@domain.com', 'example2@domain.com', 'example3@domain.com)
#the number of addresses is actually not defined
```

Comment: You can use `address: ['address1','address2'...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaml syntax for arrays would be:

```
address: 
    - example@domain.com
    - example2@domain.com
    - example3@domain
```

or

```
address: ["example1@domain.com", "example2@domain.com"]
```

but i dont know if symfony supports this.

Comment: Yes symfony support this format : 
`address: ["example1@domain.com", "example2@domain.com"]`
See http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html